# Fetching the value of a mdl-textfield

Tags: material-design-lite

I have the following mdl-textfield:

```
       <div class="mdl-textfield mdl-js-textfield" id="step_condition">
            <textarea class="mdl-textfield__input" type="text" rows="25"> </textarea>
            <label class="mdl-textfield__label" for="step_json">Step condition</label>
        </div>
```

To set the value of the field I use:

```
 $("#step_condition").get(0).MaterialTextfield.change('100');
```

My questions are:

- is this the correct way of setting the value of the field?
- is there a similar way to fetch the value of the field?

I know I can fetch the value directly from the textarea, but somehow it seems to make more sense to use the API.

Answer (score 1):

You should add an id to the textarea itself, like:

```
<div class="mdl-textfield mdl-js-textfield" >
   <textarea class="mdl-textfield__input" type="text" rows="25" id="step_json"></textarea>
   <label class="mdl-textfield__label" for="step_json">Step condition</label>
</div>
```

Look at the example on the official specifications, there is no id at the div level. http://www.getmdl.io/components/index.html#textfields-section

To set up the value of the field you could do

```
$("#step_json").val("100");
```

However you will have to deal with the fact that the label is not removed automatically. This post should help: https://github.com/google/material-design-lite/issues/903

Comment: Yes, I understand adding an id to the item, but it seems strange to me, setting a value through the api and fetching it directly from the item. I use $("#step_condition").get(0).MaterialTextfield.change('100'); because of the label. Now I need 2 id's for one item. Doesn't add up, hence the question.

Comment: @JasperDuizendstra   I agree with you, using var myValue =  $("#step_json").val(); is not very consistent with how the value is changed.